# Resharper suggests to make inherited class as sealed

Tags: c#, resharper

I've this Piece of code:

```
  public class Tag : ValueObjectBase
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual long Count { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        protected override void Validate()
        {
        }
```

and I just inherit the NewsTag class from Tag like this:

```
 public class NewsTag : Tag
    {
        public NewsTag(string name, int count)
        {
            Count = count;
            Name = name;
        }

        protected override void Validate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

why Does Resharper suggest me to make the NewsTag class as sealed??

Comment: why it should suggest you ? what is the point of making nested class sealed ?

Comment: @Selman22: The same as making any other class sealed... although there's no indication that it's nested, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean what is special about nested class ? in order to keep nested class count simple in the inheritance chain?

Comment: @Selman22: I don't understand - the question didn't mention nested classes, so why did you introduce them into the conversation? There's very little that's particularly different about them, other than that they can be private.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I mean inherited class :)) I'm just confused,I'm trying to figure out what is the reason of making an inherited class sealed

Comment: @Selman22: *Every* class you write inherits from something, if you think about it. The point of sealing a class derived from one of your other classes is the same as sealing any other class: design for inheritance or prohibit it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just removed the virtual keyword and it didn't suggest anymore! but I can't find out the reason of that

Comment: @JonSkeet you right.but OP write "why **Does't** Resharper suggest" and I though it doesn't suggest and he wants a custom suggestion that's why I'm confused,I guess it was just a typo:)

Comment: @JonSkeet oh god! I'm so so sorry about the type mistake, just edited it, "why does resharper suggest to make it seald? "